# How to use if else condition in one button with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building a VPN application with flutter. After users write their server, username, and password they used to click the 'connect' button. But for now, I have two buttons that contain connect and disconnect functions.

connect function:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text('Connect'),
  onPressed: () => FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
    server: _addressController.text,
    username: _usernameController.text,
    password: _passwordController.text,
  ),
),
```

disconnect function:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text('Disconnect'),
  onPressed: () => FlutterVpn.disconnect(),
),
```

My question is, how to combine those 2 functions above become one button? Thank you in advance for any help.

I've tried this, but it throws me an error.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async{
    if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected){
      child: Text('Connect'),
      FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
        server: _addressController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      );
    }else{
      child: const Text('Disconnect')
      onPressed: () => FlutterVpn.disconnect();
    }
  }
),
```

Comment: You should probably check the interactivity tutorial again: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive specifically the part about "Managing State". Also maybe this tutorial: https://flutter-examples.com/change-text-widget-text-dynamically/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it use ternary expression like `checkUp? if true:else` for text and `if-else` conditional statement will work fine and looks better on `onPressed`.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async{
    if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected){
      FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
        server: _addressController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      );
    }else{
      FlutterVpn.disconnect();
    }
  },
  child: Text(state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected?'Connect':'Disconnect'),
),
```

I will recommend you to check [conditional-expressions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions)

Comment: glad to help,, you can explore flutter.dev for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally set the value of `Text` this way:

```
Text(state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected ? 'Connect' : 'Disconnect'),
```